# How to use vfork to create multiple process?

Tags: linux, operating-system, fork, vfork

This is program for vfork(). This program creates multiple parent and child processes and return -1 at the end (mean OS cannot create another process). Why such behaviour happens?

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
  int pid;
  pid=vfork();
  printf("pid=%d\n",pid);
  if(pid==0)
  {
    printf("hello\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't use the *obsolete* `vfork` syscall; always use [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) which is quite efficient! Use `perror` on failure.

Answer (score 2):

(1) This creates a single child.

(2) With `vfork` the child shares memory with the parent until either `exec` or `_exit` are called.  You call neither.

(3) The parent's execution is suspended until the child calls `exec` or `_exit`.

So basically your example is FUBAR.  The point of `vfork` (if there really is one these days) is to provide a fast `fork` mechanism that will immediately `exec` another program.  The need for this has been vastly diminished with the copy-on-write behavior of regular `fork`.

Comment: If parent execution is suspended then why it is going in "if(pid>0)" condition. It should not execute this condition.

Comment: It isn't.  On my system the following occurs. (1) child prints pid=0; (2) child prints "hello"; (3) child crashes at_exit(); (4) parent resumes and prints its pid.

Comment: then why parent is creating another child and going in a loop?

Comment: Because you must be running some other program than this one.